# Regex replace('/color[1-9]?[0-9]/g','') not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to remove all occurrences of color1...color99 from a string in JavaScript.
I wrote a simple regex for this, but it doesn't work for some reason:

```
> 'color12'.replace('/color[1-9]?[0-9]/g','')
'color12'
```

However if I create RegExp object, it works:

```
> var regex=new RegExp('color[1-9]?[0-9]','g');
> 'color12'.replace(regex,'');
''
```

What part of JavaScript regexp syntax am I missing?

Comment: Remove the quotes from the REGEX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Documentation, the replace function takes input an **Regex Object or a substring** , and **an replacement string**.

> The replace() method returns a new string with some or all matches of
>   a pattern replaced by a replacement.  The pattern can be a string or a
>   RegExp, and the replacement can be a string or a function to be called
>   for each match. Syntax
>
> str.replace(regexp|substr, newSubStr|function[,   flags]);
>
> Returns
>
> A new string with some or all matches of a pattern replaced by a
>   replacement. Parameters
>
> regexp
>       A RegExp object. The match is replaced by the return value of parameter #2.
>
> substr
>       A String that is to be replaced by newSubStr.
>
> newSubStr
>       The String that replaces the substring received from parameter #1. A number of special replacement patterns are supported; see the
>   "Specifying a string as a parameter" section below.

In your case, it takes the first argument as a substring. Since 'color12' does not have a substring such as '/color[1-9]?[0-9]/g', it doesn't get replaced.

If you change it to,

```
'color12'.replace(/color[1-9]?[0-9]/g,'')
```

The first expression now is treated as a RegEx Object and the function returns the appropriate result.

**Read More:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 1):

Your first method is interpreting the regex as a string.

```
'color12'.replace(/color[1-9]?[0-9]/g, '')
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
'color12'.replace(/color[1-9]?[0-9]/g, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes from the REGEX

```
      'color12'.replace(/color[1-9]?[0-9]/g,'')
```

will work better

Comment: And this was downvoted why? It was the first correct answer of the 4 identical answers

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code :

```
str = 'abscolor12ikg';
regex=new RegExp('color[1-9]?[0-9]','g');
str = str.replace(regex,'');
alert(str)
```

It display absikg

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/245dghjm/)